# server that responds on any port

Tags: server, nmap, ports, scan

I want to make a server that responds `open` to every port that is scanned by nmap (TCP and UDP).

Are there a simple solution to do that?

Comment: This really isn't a security question, but a programming question or a server config question.

Comment: iptables can redirect all traffic to a certain port

Comment: Are you building a server to test nmap on, or some sort of device to trick people nmap scanning you? Do you still want other services ti function normally on your server (ftp / http etc)

Comment: Could you elaborate your question a little bit more? Would you like to create a honeypot and eavesdrop traffic? or would you like to all your traffic be redirected to one application? Or is it as simple as showing all open on nmap?

Comment: I want to test a connection between 2 distant points. The first make a nmap to a server i want to do. And i want this one responds open to every port to check if the connection block some ports. I realize it's not a security question, but i don't know where i have to ask my question. Sorry for inconvenience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just port-forward (i.e. DNAT) anything incoming from certain ranges to a single port with a generic listener of some form on it.

Something like:

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 1.1.1.1/24 -p tcp --dports 0:65535 -j DNAT --to-port 8080`

Obviously, whether or not that *actually* works for your purposes depends on your use-case.